# Proving if $H$ is subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if $H$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

(a) $H$ consists of all the vectors in $\Bbb R$.
3 with the product of all the components equal to $0$;

(b) $H$ consists of all the vectors in $\Bbb R$
3 with the first component equal to $1$;

(c) $H$ consists of all the vectors in $\Bbb R$
3 with the first component equal to $0$;

(d) H consists of all the vectors
$[2a − b;
2b − c;
2c − a]$

with $a,b,c$ all real numbers.

Can someone show me how to prove it by showing whether or not the $0$ vector of $\Bbb R^3$ is in $H$, that the addition is closed, and that multiplying it by a scalar $c$ is closed?

Comment: I think that problems like this are wonderful exercises in using the basic definitions, and it's really too bad they get asked and answered here. One's typical strategy is to look for a particular example showing that something isn't a subspace (e.g. find two vectors in the set whose sum is not). If you can't find an example after trying a bit, it probably is a subspace, and you've learned something about why it is -- which will help you prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a hint if something is a subspace then it will have to satisfy the fact it closed under scalar multiplication. It is obvious for the first one.

I will prove for you the first one and the others follow pretty much same procedure:

Let U denote our candidate subspace :
For A $\in$ U, B $\in$ U we have A = ($x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$) such that $x_1*y_1*z_1$ = 0 same thing for B. A*B = ($x_1 + x_2$,$y_1 + y_2$,$z_1 + z_2$)  we will have ($x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)(z_1 + z_2)$ we can see there it can be that it won't be the case that it is closed because you have some extra terms that can be not zero.

Similar argument for scalar multiplication.

In those question just make sure you once you do addition or scalar multiplication you get same form for the subspace U that is defined.

Comment: hmm, ok I think I understand. For 1, (x1+x2)(y1+y2)(z1+z2) can equal 0 but not in every case, which is the restriction for A and so because of that, it's not closed. Am I right?

For 2, I'm guessing that adding 1+1 = 2, so the first term would not be 1 and the restriction is broken.

For 3, 0+0 = 0, and when you add 2 vectors like that together, it would still be in the same form as the original.

For 4, I guess adding 2 vectors like that would come out to something like 2d-e for the first equation, where d would be like 2a and e is j+k. Basically, the form is the same.

Comment: What I don't understand is, how do I know the 0 vector is in it and how do I show it's closed by multiplying a c scalar for 3 and 4?

Comment: To check if its a zero exist you there are two conventions either show the 0 vector must be of some satisfies the form of your subspace that is one convention by considering the zero vector as separate thing that you need to prove, however I don't like this convention you can just prove that it closed under scalar multiplication then it must be true that 0 * X = 0 for any X $\in$ U.